# SQL SERVER, Import from CSV. "Failure inserting into the read-only column "id"."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is similar: [SSIS: "Failure inserting into the read-only column <ColumnName>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931129/ssis-failure-inserting-into-the-read-only-column-columnname)

This is my error

[image: Image of error]

Comment: You need to include enough information to replicate the problem directly in your question. Don't link another question because if it **is the same problem** then your question should be closed as duplicate. Also, you need to include the error message directly in your question... not a picture of the error (although feel free to also include the screenshot as supporting evidence)

Comment: The error and the answers for the linked post seem pretty clear: You are trying to insert values into an IDENTIY column.

Comment: Rather than relying on someone else's (very old) question (that thing is almost 9 years old), please put the effort in to ask about your own scenario. [Help Centre - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS: "Failure inserting into the read-only column <ColumnName>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931129/ssis-failure-inserting-into-the-read-only-column-columnname)

Comment: @Filburt , So how do I exclude the ID column?

Comment: Take it out of the mapping on the flow control target.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had to click "Edit Mappings" and "Enable Identity insert"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu3iY.png)